# Get closest point based on coordinates

Tags: r, coordinates, distance, euclidean-distance

I'd like to snap single points to other points based on their distance in R.
In detail, I have a bunch of points defined by X and Y coordinate pairs.
In addition I have single different points, that I want to snap to
the closest neighbors (euclidean distance).

```
# target points
df <- data.frame(X=c(1,2,2,2,3,4),Y=c(1,2,2,3,3,4))

# points that need snapping
point1 <- data.frame(X=2.1, Y=2.3)
point2 <- data.frame(X=2.5, Y=2.5)


plot(df)
points(point1$X,point1$Y,pch=20,col="red")
points(point2$X,point2$Y,pch=20,col="blue")
```

But how to proceed with the snapping of the points? 
 How can I snap the points and assign new coordinate pairs to the single points?
Is there a simple function available in R? Or do I need to apply
the dist() function to obtain a distance matrix and search for
the closest distance? Maybe there is a more straight forward way.

Thats how it should look like:

1) snap to the closest (euclidean distance) point (clear solution for point 1)

```
point1$X_snap <- 2
point1$Y_snap <- 2
```

2) if two or more points similarily close than
snap to that which is more "north-east"
a) snap first to the one which is more north (Y direction)
b) if there are more than one that a similarly distant in Y direction snap
to the one that is more east

```
point2$X_snap <- 3
point2$Y_snap <- 3
```

For a graphical illustration how the results should look like

```
#plot snapped points:
points(point1$X_snap,point1$Y_snap,pch=8,col="red")
points(point2$X_snap,point2$Y_snap,pch=8,col="blue")
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible using `dist`:

```
 dist(rbind(point1,df))
          1         2         3         4         5
2 1.7029386                                        
3 0.3162278 1.4142136                              
4 0.3162278 1.4142136 0.0000000                    
5 0.7071068 2.2360680 1.0000000 1.0000000          
6 1.1401754 2.8284271 1.4142136 1.4142136 1.0000000
7 2.5495098 4.2426407 2.8284271 2.8284271 2.2360680
          6
2          
3          
4          
5          
6          
7 1.4142136
```

So the row with the minimum value (distance) in the first column identifies the point in `df` which is closest to `point1` .  In your example, you have a repeated location.  Repeat for each of your `point_x` .

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution using the matchpt() function
from Biobase (Bioconductor):

```
# target points
df <- data.frame(X=c(1,2,2,2,3,4),Y=c(1,2,2,3,3,4))

# points that need snapping
point1 <- data.frame(X=2.1, Y=2.3)
point2 <- data.frame(X=2.5, Y=2.5)

snap <- function(df,point){
  require(Biobase)
  d <- matchpt(as.matrix(df),
               as.matrix(data.frame(X=point$X+0.0001,Y=point$Y+0.0001))) # to the "northwest" criteria correct

  min_row <- as.numeric(rownames(d[d$distance==min(d$distance),]))

  point$X_snap <- unique(df[min_row,"X"])
  point$Y_snap <- unique(df[min_row,"Y"])

  point
}

snap(df,point2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to try the [`RANN` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RANN/index.html) for Fast Nearest Neighbour Search:

```
# your data
df <- data.frame(X=c(1,2,2,2,3,4),Y=c(1,2,2,3,3,4))
pts <- data.frame(X=c(2.1, 2.5), Y=c(2.3, 2.5))
library(RANN)
# for each point in pts, find the nearest neighbor from df
closest <- RANN::nn2(data = df, query = pts, k = 1)
# argument k sets the number of nearest neighbours, here 1 (the closest)
closest
# $nn.idx
# [,1]
# [1,]    3
# [2,]    5
# 
# $nn.dists
# [,1]
# [1,] 0.3162278
# [2,] 0.7071068
# Get coordinates of nearest neighbor
pts$X_snap <- df[closest$nn.idx, "X"]
pts$Y_snap <- df[closest$nn.idx, "Y"]
pts
#     X   Y X_snap Y_snap
# 1 2.1 2.3      2      2
# 2 2.5 2.5      3      3
```

Answer (score 0):

I would put the criteria (distance, "southness", "westness") in a dataframe and then sort this dataframe along these criteria:

```
# input data
df <- data.frame(X=c(1,2,2,2,3,4),Y=c(1,2,2,3,3,4))
point1 <- data.frame(X=2.1, Y=2.3)
point2 <- data.frame(X=2.5, Y=2.5)
df.res[with(df.res, order(dst, dy, dx)), ]

# function that sorts all potential snapping points according to distance, "westness", "southness"
snap.xy <- function(point, other.points) {
  df.res <- data.frame(X = other.points$X,   # to later access the coordinates to snap to
                       Y = other.points$Y,   # dto
                       dx <- point$X - other.points$X, # "westness" (the higher, the more "west")
                       dy <- point$Y - other.points$Y, # "southness"
                       dst = sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2))        # distance
  # print(df.res[with(df.res, order(dst, dy, dx)), ])  # just for checking the results
  return(df.res[with(df.res, order(dst, dy, dx)), ][1,c("X", "Y")])  # return only the X/Y coordinates
}

# examples
snap.xy(point1, df)    # 2/2
snap.xy(point2, df)    # 3/3
snap.xy(point2, df)$X  # 3
snap.xy(point2, df)$Y  # 3
```